# Filtering NSFetchedResultsController at the model layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I need help to think about and implement filtering of `NSFetchedResultsController`'s `fetchedObjects` **at the model layer**.

Docs say:

> #### Responding to Changes
>
> In general, `NSFetchedResultsController` is designed to respond to changes at the model layer, by informing its
>   delegate when result objects change location or when sections are
>   modified.
>
> [NSFetchedResultsController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html)

For example, how could one implement search at the model layer?

I imagine a `Filter` entity which is somehow related to the entities being filtered, and is used in the `NSFetchRequest`'s predicate.

Maybe I would create a `Filter` object, configure it with, say, a string from a search field, and then save the object. This would affect the `NSFetchRequest`'s predicate, so the `NSFetchedResultsController` would get the private messages for updating its `fetchedObjects` and issue messages to its delegate.

I could create other `Filter` objects (or change existing ones) which further affects the `NSFetchedResultsController`'s `fetchedObjects`, and that, when deleted, stop affecting `fetchedObjects`, which are then 'visible' again.

- What would the model look like in Xcode's model editor?
- What would the `NSFetchRequest`'s predicate look like?
- What are drawbacks with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Wain. The model layer is not the suitable mechanism to update a list when searching.

Instead, modify the `predicate` of the `fetchRequest` of the `NSFetchedResultsController` and re-fetch. This is a common pattern for implementing search with a `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to work. Your fetch would be directed at entity A and use a predicate related to entity B which holds some configuration that you update. The FRC is only monitoring changes to entity A, not entity B, so when you change the configuration it won't be picked up so no trigger for the delegate.

The only way to do it is to update the predicate and restart the FRC. The alternate being to somehow encode the information into entity A, but if you can do that you don't need the FRC as you already have all of the new search results before the FRC knows about it...

Answer (score 0):

With this approach, you would need to create a `Filter` object for each result object for `NSFetchedResultsController` to pick it up. These kinds of tricks can be applied to modify user-driven sorting and sectioning but for filtering, you're better off using a predicate on `NSFetchRequest` which filters on actual model data.

Unless you want to do some very specific filtering which can't be done by using only the original model data. In that case it would be an alternative but you would still have to create a `Filter` object for each underlying data object.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Alek. The point of course is that the underlying mechanisms of NSFetchedResultsController do not respond to changes in the NSFetchRequest's predicate (without re-fetching), which is what I want to achieve: filtering while relying on the already existing under-the-hood change observations.

Comment: Alright, so what you want is to change the predicate runtime and get notified of the resulted changes in the dataset?

Comment: Yes: To get notified of those changes through the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol.